# Не работает JS после Ajax контента

Tags: javascript

Почему не работает JS после Ajax контента?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6">
            <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
    $("#loader").show();
    $("#main").hide();
    $('body').append("<div id='result'></div>");
    var urlf = "lib/test1.php";
    var urls = "lib/test2.php";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async:false,
        url: urlf,
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#loader").hide();
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=data;

        }
    });
});
```

После загрузки контента не работает ни одна js-ка из подгруженного контента test.php

Comment: Добрый день. Ну так посмотрите в консоли браузера, какие там ошибки.

Comment: JS не работает, потому что данных из подгружаемых страниц в DOM просто нет, обрабатывать нечего и некому. Запускайте свои скрипты (например, через функции) после загрузки контента в блок.

Comment: Ошибок никаких, можете привести пример кода?

Comment: У вас `test.php` возращает js код? Что значит, не работает js-ка?

Comment: test.php возвращает некий html в котором присутствует и  js подгружает все кроме  js

Answer (score 0):

Решил, Если кому то надо:

```
    var div = document.getElementById('result');
                var obj= div.getElementsByTagName('script');
                var len = obj.length;
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
                {
                    eval(obj[i].text);
                }

            }
```